# How to set bottom border using css in QTextBrowser?

Tags: python, css, pyside2, qtextbrowser

Suppose I have a QT window (using Pyside2, like PyQT5) with the following widget:

```py
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextBrowser

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

main_window = QMainWindow()
html_string = """
<style>
td { border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; color: blue }
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
"""
text_browser = QTextBrowser()
text_browser.setHtml(html_string)
text_browser.setReadOnly(True)

main_window.setCentralWidget(text_browser)

main_window.show()

exit_code = app.exec_()
sys.exit(exit_code)
```

I expect the widget to display the table with bottom borders. Something like this:

[image: expected]

(image: table with bottom borders).

But I get this:

[image: actual]

(image: table without borders).

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/richtext-html-subset.html#supported-html-subset) suggests however that border styles using css are supported on table cells.

- **Note**: that using inline style like `<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000">` makes no difference.
- **Note2**: I'm only trying to have a bottom border, so setting `<table border="1">` does not give a desirable result.

Does anyone have an idea on whether this can be achieved at all, and if so, how?

Comment: How strange: I do get the bottom borders: https://i.imgur.com/OI50tzl.png

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks, I'll have to look at other things then this directly, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I used PySide2-5.13.0 with shiboken2-5.13.0. After updating them both to 5.14.0 it now works as expected.